# Pandas merge adding column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`. `df1` contains the columns `subject_id` and `time` and `df2` contains the columns `subject_id` and `final_time`. What I want to do is for every `subject_id` in `df1` add a column with  `final_time` from `df2` but only from the `subject_ids`'s contained in `df1`. I have tried `df1.merge(df2,how='left')` but still get all of the `subject_id`'s from `df2` which is much longer and contains many duplicates of 'subject_id`.

Example of what I am looking for:

```
df1


    subject_id  time  

 0          15  12:00 
 1          20  12:05 
 2          21  12:10
 3          25  12:00 

df2


    subject_id  final_time 

 0          15       12:30      
 1          15       12:30      
 2          15       12:30      
 3          20       12:45      
 4          20       12:45      
 5          21       12:50      
 6          25        1:00       
 7          25        1:00       
 8          25        1:00
```

What I am looking for

```
    subject_id  time  final_time 

 0          15  12:00      12:30      
 1          20  12:05      12:45      
 2          21  12:10      12:50      
 3          25  12:00       1:00
```

Comment: Can you show example code, and what the intended output would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use

```
df1.merge(df2, on='subject_id')
```

The default for `how` is inner, which will only match those entries that are in both columns. `on` tells the merge to match only on the column you are interested in

Comment: Just edited my questions, `df2` contains duplicates of `subject_id` which I think is causing this to give the same results as I was getting with `df1.merge(df2,how='left')`

Comment: If you only want the unique rows from `df2` joined to the matching rows on `df1` try dropping the duplicates from `df2` first. So `df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates())`

Comment: `.drop_duplicates()` looks to be what I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.  Nothing in results that aren't in `df1`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(subject_id=[1, 2, 3], time=[9, 8, 7]))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(subject_id=[2, 2, 4], final_time=[6, 5, 4]))

df1.merge(df2, 'left')

   subject_id  time  final_time
0           1     9         NaN
1           2     8         6.0
2           2     8         5.0
3           3     7         NaN
```